# Concatenating multiple JPEG Sequences to one mp4 file

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I have multiple **JPEG** Sequences

```
/mydir/A/preview.%04d.jpg
/mydir/B/preview.%04d.jpg
```

and i want to output them as output.mp4

One single shot works fine like that:

```
ffmpeg -i "/mydir/A/preview.%04d.jpg" output.mp4
```

And it works as well with a txt file containing the files.

mylist.txt

```
file '/mydir/A/preview.%04d.jpg'
file '/mydir/B/preview.%04d.jpg'
```

ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt output.mp4

But i would like to generate a command on the fly without outputting something extra on disc!

PS: i am linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the concat filter:

```
ffmpeg -i "/mydir/A/preview.%04d.jpg" -i "/mydir/B/preview.%04d.jpg" \
       -filter_complex [0][1]concat=n=2 output.mp4
```